# Trying to define variables to specific memory locations

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, winavr

Hey, im using WinAVR and programing an ATMEGA32 in C.
Basically, I want to link my C program to asm via the:

> asm(" ") command.

Im trying to define memory locations in C to exact memory locations so that I can then access them within the asm command line.

I have 5 variables:

> unsigned char var1, var2, var3, var4,
>   var5;

I know I could use pointers to a memory location, but im unsure how to do this.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Oliver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is completely compiler-independent, simple, and straightforward:

```
#define var1 (*(volatile unsigned char *)0xDEADBEEF)
#define var2 (*(volatile unsigned char *)0xDECAFBAD)
#define var3 (*(volatile unsigned char *)0xBADC0DE)
```

etc.

Comment: You should use `volatile unsigned char` instead of `unsigned char`. This will ensure that the compiler doesn't optimize away reads/writes from/to the memory locations.

Comment: I've defined those statements; now Im trying to access the variable in my C program:  var1 = new_key.  This returns a syntax error, i've tried playing around with pointers such as *var1 = new_key but to no avail...

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Are you really writing C, or are you writing C++?

Comment: The define statements work. But accessing them is returning a syntax error. var1 = new_key; this returns the error:../MorseOut.c:43: error: syntax error before '=' token in winAVR. Im 99% sure this is C, not C++... Both var1 and new_key are volatile unsigned char's...

Comment: Did you perhaps mistakenly put a semicolon at the end of your `#define` lines? Show the actual code that's giving syntax errors (both the `#define` and the place you use it) since I'm nearly certain this is a simple typo.

Comment: Yes your right, I added semicolons at the end of the define statements. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Semicolons belong at the end of statements, but `#define` is not a statement, it's a preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 3):

You can access memory locations by their C variable names with inline assembler using GCC. Please refer to the [AVR-GCC Inline Assembler Cookbook](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html) for more information. You can also place C variables at exact memory locations using compiler extensions or linker scripts. However, the whole point of compilers and assemblers is so that we don't have to manage tedious details like that.